# PDO Join, avoid overwriting keys with the same name in the resulted array

Tags: arrays, pdo

I am doing a join with PDO like this:

```
SELECT users.*,images.*, sessions.*,social.*,videos.*,teams.*,achievements.*,_achievements_list.* FROM users LEFT JOIN images ON users.user_id=images.user_id LEFT JOIN sessions ON users.user_id=sessions.user_id LEFT JOIN social ON users.user_id=social.user_id LEFT JOIN videos ON users.user_id=videos.user_id LEFT JOIN teams ON users.user_id=teams.user_id LEFT JOIN achievements ON users.user_id=achievements.user_id LEFT JOIN _achievements_list ON achievements.achievement_id=_achievements_list.parent_id WHERE users.nickname = 'something'
```

The problem is that some tables have the same names for some columns, so in the array that PDO gives me back, many things are overwritten.

I am using this:

```
   $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);

    if ($statement->execute($param))
        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return false;
```

PDO returns an associative array, but how do I do in order to avoid overwriting columns with the same names but from different tables?

Comment: use FETCH_ALL instead of FETCH_ASSOC, I think you'll have everything that way (2 twice: once by number and once by column name)

Comment: exactly the same question a week ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17715049/285587

Comment: Another way would be to make different queries to all these tables.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `PDO::FETCH_NAMED`, see https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_NAMED

Answer (score -2):

- it is very not recommended to use .* because :

  1. if the table structure changes, then your column indexes change, and if you used to read by index, then Too bad.
  2. mostly, you really dont need all the columns and therefore you will reduce the amount of data you retrieve from the server (if it is remote then it might even be meanningful)

Anyway, if you dont use .* you can use Aliases in your SQL Query
like

```
SELECT products.id prodId, orders.id orderId FROM Orders LEFT JOIN Products ON (prodId = orders.product_id) WHERE orderId = @oid
```

Comment: Can you clarify (1) please? It seems contrary to me - even if column indexes change, there would be no need to rewrite the query. What's wrong with it?

Comment: i ment consider query `Select * from myTable` where `MyTable: ID,fldA,FldB,FldC`
using myRecord[2] <= by index will result in getting fldB.
and (1) if you change your table schema, remove fldA, it will return FldC instead of FldB.
(2) if you delete FldB or change it's name, you will get a behaviour bug rather then a simple Error that is much harder to intercept.

Comment: in PHP we usually address fields by the names, not positions. So, it would be not a problem.