# How to return mysql data using table aliases with left join and duplicate columns

Tags: mysql, mysqli

I am trying to do a simple left join, while using table aliases, to return all of the values from both tables in this format:

```
[Alias1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [city] => bay area
        [state] => CA
    )

[Alias2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [city] => san francisco
        [baseball_team] => giants

     )
```

Here is my very simple mysqli_query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($sql, SELECT  Alias1.id, Alias1.city, Alias1.state, Alias2.id, Alias2.city, Alias2.baseball_team FROM database.table1 AS Alias1 LEFT JOIN database.table2 AS Alias2 ON Alias1.id = Alias2.id)
```

To get the results... I use:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
     $data[] = $row;
}
print_r($data);die();
```

**Problem:** The data prints out as such:

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [id] => 1
            [1] => bay area
            [city] => bay area
            [2] => CA
            [state] => CA
            [3] => 1
            [4] => san francisco
            [5] => giants
            [baseball_team] => giants
        )
```

**Other Info:** I originally tried to get the data using mysql_fetch_assoc($result)... But the duplicate columns don't return at all.

Comment: show some table structure and I am sure that I can help... I would get the desired array using php and leave the query the way it is... I just need to know some of the column names... * doesn't help much.

Comment: Hey! I updated the mysqli_query to show the column names. Thanks for you help!

Comment: see my answer below for how I would do/have done it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$data[] = $row;
```

Use this to form the data array that you desire:

```
$data['Alias1'] = array(
    "id"=>$row['id'],
    "city"=>$row['1_city'],
    "state"=>$row['state'],
);
$data['Alias2'] = array(
    "id"=>$row['id'],
    "city"=>$row['2_city'],
    "baseball_team"=>$row['baseball_team'],
);
```

OR, if you expect more than one row you need to use something like:

```
$data[] = array(
    "Alias1" => array(
        "id"=>$row['id'],
        "city"=>$row['1_city'],
        "state"=>$row['state'],
    ),
    "Alias2" => array(
        "id"=>$row['id'],
        "city"=>$row['2_city'],
        "baseball_team"=>$row['baseball_team'],
    ),
);
```

**Note:**
If your city values are different between your two tables then you should use an alias so that you can pull the other one differently. If they are the same, I suggest you not have them listed twice in the database as this is duplicating data and leaves your database denormalized.

**Edit:**
Your query should be something like

```
SELECT  Alias1.id, Alias1.city AS 1_city, Alias1.state, Alias2.id, Alias2.city AS 2_city, Alias2.baseball_team FROM database.table1 AS Alias1 LEFT JOIN database.table2 AS Alias2 ON Alias1.id = Alias2.id
```

See edited answers above for these aliases.

Comment: Yes. The city values are different (just updated post). Your first response works great, except if the city values are different (as you asked). I am using Aliases in the query. And I'm pretty sure I'm using them right. It seems like the mysql_fetch_array, would have some sort of reference to the Aliases... But I don't see any?

Comment: @JustusKersey please see my edit in my answer to see how to use aliases for columns that have the same name. You can have aliases for tables as you already had and you can have aliases for columns. please refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17715434/1707323